# Terminal won't accept username when setting up git for mac

Tags: git, github, terminal

I have git installed but the following code:

> git config --global imadahmad97 "Imad Ahmad"

returns with:

```
error: key does not contain a section: imadahmad97
```

I do have a github account and have checked my username multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you are trying to set a variable called `imadahmad97` to the value `Imad Ahmad`. There is no such variable in git config.

`imadahmad97` seems to be your GitHub account name. Git and GitHub are not the same thing. GitHub is to Git what Gmail is to email. Git signs commits using your `user.name` and `user.email`. You set them like this:

```
git config --global user.name "FIRST_NAME LAST_NAME"
git config --global user.email "MY_NAME@example.com"
```

But this is not how you authenticate yourself from the terminal when pushing to a repo hosted on GitHub. Google "authenticate github in git cli" if that is what you are trying to do.

Comment: Ahh thank you! I was forgetting to add the .name

Comment: You probably want: `git config --global user.name "Imad Ahmad"`. Just adding `.name` is not a solution.